Advanced Python Grade Calculator
In this project, I've developed an Advanced Grade Calculator that not only calculates the average grade but also accounts for credit hours and predicts future performance based on historical grade trends. This tool uses an object-oriented approach, allowing for more robust data management and complex computational capabilities.
# Advanced Grade Calculator

class Course:
    def __init__(self, name, credits):
        self.name = name
        self.credits = credits
        self.grades = []

    def add_grade(self, grade):
        self.grades.append(grade)

    def average_grade(self):
        weight = {'A+': 4.3, 'A': 4.0, 'A-': 3.7, 'B+': 3.3, 'B': 3.0, 'B-': 2.7,
                  'C+': 2.3, 'C': 2.0, 'C-': 1.7, 'D': 1.0, 'F': 0.0}
        total = sum(weight[grade] for grade in self.grades)
        return total / len(self.grades) if self.grades else 0

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.courses = {}

    def add_course(self, course):
        self.courses[course.name] = course

    def calculate_gpa(self):
        total_weighted_grade = 0
        total_credits = 0
        for course in self.courses.values():
            course_avg = course.average_grade()
            total_weighted_grade += course_avg * course.credits
            total_credits += course.credits
        return total_weighted_grade / total_credits if total_credits else 0

    def predict_performance(self):
        # Basic prediction logic based on improvement trends
        improvements = []
        for course in self.courses.values():
            if len(course.grades) > 1:
                improvement = course.grades[-1] > course.grades[-2]
                improvements.append(improvement)
        prediction = "Likely to improve" if sum(improvements) / len(improvements) > 0.5 else "No significant change expected"
        return prediction

# Example usage:
student = Student("John Doe")
math = Course("Calculus", 3)
math.add_grade('B')
math.add_grade('A-')
student.add_course(math)

physics = Course("Physics", 4)
physics.add_grade('B+')
student.add_course(physics)

print(f"Calculated GPA: {student.calculate_gpa():.2f}")
print("Performance Prediction:", student.predict_performance())

This script introduces classes for both courses and students, where courses manage their own grades and credits, and the student class manages multiple courses. The calculate_gpa method in the Student class computes a weighted average based on credit hours. The predict_performance method provides a simple prediction on whether the student’s grades are likely to improve based on their past performance trend.

This codebase doesn't contain much documentation,
but perhaps it is simple enough and self-explanatory enough
that it's not really in need of much.
Given that, type annotations on signatures and
on empty container declarations would be most welcome,
as an aid to the Gentle Reader.
Plus mypy
would then be able to help check your work
as you're developing.
appropriate identifiers
The names we choose really matter, they affect how we reason about code.
        weight = {'A+': 4.3, 'A': 4.0, ...

These figures are not weights, but points
used for computing a GPA, a grade point average.
In particular, the average_grade() routine
does not use the concept of WAM, weighted average mark,
and it does not incorporate weighting according to
advanced course status or number of credit hours.
In contrast, the total_weighted_grade we see further down
is a terrific identifier.
docstring
    def predict_performance(self):
        # Basic prediction logic based on improvement trends

Turn that comment into a proper """docstring""", please.
Also, consider putting the
magic
threshold 0.5 up in the signature as a default kwarg,
to flag it as arbitrary, and
so caller can specify an alternate threshold if desired.
        prediction = "Likely to improve" if sum(improvements) / len(improvements) > 0.5 else "No significant change expected"

linear regression
predict_performance() passed up an opportunity to
use more sophisticated techniques to predict the magnitude
of a likely improvement.
Or various statistical tests, such as Student's t-test,
might be employed: for an individual learner,
across the whole population taking a course,
or everyone enrolled at the school.
main guard
Thank you for illustrating the example usage. Consider putting that
code within def main(): or def example_usage():.
And protect it with the usual if __name__ == "__main__": idiom, so
unit tests
can safely import this module without unwanted side effects.

The program design doesn't need mutation - so don't allow it; make all of your data structures immutable.
The concept of a "student" with a name doesn't really apply to this OOP design, only a program attempt, course attempt, and course definition. To that end, you should separate your classes a little.
WEIGHT should be a global or at least a class static.
The standard library is your friend - use statistics for both a mean and a linear regressor as JH suggests.
Your logic for an empty grade sequence is troubled. If a student has a good record of previous courses, and then enters a new course for which they haven't submitted any work yet, should that really (severely) count against their GPA? Probably not. Instead of assuming 0 for all empty-sequence course grades, you should probably just remove its effect from the GPA. I do not demonstrate this.
Move your demo code to a function.
Use PEP484 type hinting and the new type keyword.
Suggested
import statistics
from typing import NamedTuple, Literal

type GradeStr = Literal[
    'A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D', 'F',
]

WEIGHT: dict[GradeStr, float] = {
    'A+': 4.3, 'A': 4.0, 'A-': 3.7, 'B+': 3.3, 'B': 3.0, 'B-': 2.7,
    'C+': 2.3, 'C': 2.0, 'C-': 1.7, 'D': 1.0, 'F': 0.0,
}


class Course(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    credits: int

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


class CourseAttempt(NamedTuple):
    course: Course
    grades: tuple[GradeStr, ...]

    @property
    def grade_values(self) -> tuple[float, ...]:
        return tuple(
            WEIGHT[grade] for grade in self.grades
        )

    @property
    def mean(self) -> float:
        if len(self.grades) == 0:
            return 0
        return statistics.fmean(self.grade_values)

    @property
    def next_predicted_grade(self) -> float:
        n = len(self.grades)
        match n:
            case 0:
                return 0
            case 1:
                return self.grade_values[0]
            case _:
                slope, intercept = statistics.linear_regression(
                    range(n),  # x
                    self.grade_values,  # y
                )
                return slope*n + intercept

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.course}: {self.mean:.2f}'


class ProgramAttempt(NamedTuple):
    courses: tuple[CourseAttempt, ...]

    @property
    def gpa(self) -> float:
        if len(self.courses) == 0:
            return 0
        return statistics.fmean(
            data=[attempt.mean for attempt in self.courses],
            weights=[attempt.course.credits for attempt in self.courses],
        )


def demo() -> None:
    year = ProgramAttempt(
        courses=(
            CourseAttempt(
                course=Course(name='Calculus', credits=3),
                grades=('B', 'A-'),
            ),
            CourseAttempt(
                course=Course(name='Physics', credits=4),
                grades=('B+',),
            ),
        ),
    )

    print(f'GPA: {year.gpa:.2f}')

    print('Predicted grades per course:')
    for course in year.courses:
        print(f'    {course} -> {course.next_predicted_grade:.2f}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()

GPA: 3.32
Predicted grades per course:
    Calculus: 3.35 -> 4.40
    Physics: 3.30 -> 3.30

